# Different keys for "Ctrl+Backspace" in xterm vs LXTerminal

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, xterm, lxterminal

I'm comming from Windows an GUI applications, so I'm used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to be the keyword-delete mapping.

I'm also used to `bash` and Terminal emulator (LXTerminal now, but also with Ubuntu's Terminal), so I've searched about keymapping, but I couldn't find my situacion or fix it.

In [this superuser answer tells to re-map key](https://superuser.com/a/837764), but when asking what is mapped with `sudo showkeys -a` there is:

```
^?  127 0177 0x7f  # 'backspace'
^?  127 0177 0x7f  # 'ctrl'+'backspace'
```

Says the same. Ok, no way to map because both will be doing the same. But! Doing the same command in the xterm application, output is:

```
^?  127 0177 0x7f  # 'backspace'
^H    8 0010 0x08  # diferent 'ctrl'+'backspace'!!!!
```

Would I be able to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> keyword-delete in LXTerminal?
Is wrong somewhere LXTerminal? Or is xterm?

P.S.: I didn't test if I would be able to map the shortcut in xterm, I'll test it later.

Comment: So what's your main question ? You're asking to re-map the key ? or you want the answer to address why it's not working in LXTerminal ?

Comment: For the record, word-deleting shortcut is set to  Ctrl+W

Comment: My main question is if I can map Ctrl+Backspace in LXTerminal, I'll try to make it more clear. About shortcut, in linked question already says, but I'm used to the GUI way :)

Comment: LXTerminal uses an almost 5 year old and no longer maintained version of the Gtk2 branch of the terminal emulation widget called Vte. It contains plenty of bugs, including sending the wrong sequence for Ctrl+Backspace being one of them. The Gtk3 branch of Vte recently fixed this bug, and in turn Ubuntu Xenial's default Terminal (gnome-terminal) will have it work as expected.